# Cannot set property 'selectedIndex' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am having `select tag`

How to access document elements and assign the value?

After **executing** this I get this **error**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectedIndex' of undefined

This is my JavaScript code

```
  let gender = document.getElementsByClassName('genderClass');
  gender[0].selectedIndex = 2;
```

This is my HTML code

```
     <html>
        <body>
           <select class="genderClass" >
             <option  size="7" value="">Gender</option>
             <option  size="7" value="M">Male</option>
             <option  size="7" value="F">Female</option>
             <option  size="7" value="T">Transgender</option>
           </select>
        </body>
      <html>
```

can some one please help me.

Comment: where are you setting selectedIndex ?

Comment: the code you posted  is not the code that is responsible for that error - your browser developer tools should tell you which line of your code is responsible for that error - if not, use a better browser

Comment: gender[0].selectedIndex = 2;

Comment: what you wanna do? as i can see code is working fine

Comment: OT however, your gender list is quite limited. Do you really need to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check if `gender[0]` is defined and is an object.
If yes, try this:

```
gender[0]['selectedIndex'] = 2;
```

By the way, `gender[0].selectedIndex = 2;` should also work if `gender[0]` is defined and is an object.

**Update:
Adding your script after the `<body></body>` tag might solve your problem.**

Comment: that is my question already it is saying that gender[0] is undefined but how is it possible i defined it in html

Comment: it is saying that gender[0] is not defined but how its possible? and if it is not defined how to define it?

Comment: try adding a breakpoint at let gender = document.getElementsByClassName('genderClass'); and then check the value

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check. If it solves your problem, please mark it as accepted.